# Flutter No SQL DB - Is there any stable no-sql database with efficient query on nested JSON object

Tags: sqlite, flutter, nosql

I need to insert and query nested objects in DB. I think the relational database would not be a better choice for it. Structure of the json is

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "age": "24",
  addresses: [
    {
      "address_line1": "abc",
      "address_line2": "xyz",
      "city": "abc"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried sembast and hive. In Hive, query support is not present and sembast will not work efficiently with large data sets.

Is their any stable no SQL solution with efficient query capability available for Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

Sembast loads everything in memory when opening the database so its main limitation is the memory available (and likely initial start performance). I'm not sure it is the best candidate for 50k records. SQLite has good query performance but it does not fit your requirements.

Your best bet would be to find a native no SQL database (Realm, Couchbase, whatever exists that fits your need) and find or write the appropriate plugin for it.

It could also be possible to create a noSQL wrapper on top of SQLite (idb_sqflite being an example but with no good query capabilities).

Comment: Can we do a query on nested json object in idb_sqflite.

Comment: idb_sqflite basically implements IndexedDB on top of SQLite. Query on indexedDB is limited. You can however query by range on a nested field using index. The full (not very dartish) API is described here: https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB but I guess you can find some examples (likely in javascript though) elsewhere.